# How can i get the document title in Office 365 JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am writing an office add-in with angularjs, i need to get and set document title (that seen at that the top of the document).

this is my code:

```
function run() {
  Word.run(function (context) {
    var properties = context.document.properties;
    context.load(properties);
    return context.sync()
        .then(function() {
            console.log('thisDocument.properties.title', properties.title);
        })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    });
}
```

but in console didn't print the title of document!

Comment: Did you manage to find a sensible way of doing this in the meantime? I just fell down the same hole you did with `document.properties.title`.

Comment: @dnmh unfortunately not! I got stuck!

Answer (score 1):

The **context.document.properties.title** property that you're writing to the console is the file-level attribute **Title** that is displayed under Properties if you select **File >> Info** (in Excel running on Windows Desktop). It is not the "title" (text) that you see at that the top of your document, or the name of the file itself. I'd suspect that if you examine the file-level attribute **Title** for your document (via the Word UI), you'll see that the **Title** attribute is not populated -- it won't be populated unless you've explicitly set it.

I'm not super-familiar with the Word API object model, but here's something that might be helpful. The following code snippet gets the first paragraph of the document (which, if the first line of a document is the title, will represent the title of the document), and then updates the text of the title with a new text string (while maintaining any previous formatting, etc.).

```
Word.run(function (context) {

    // get the first paragraph 
    // (if the first line of the document is the title, this will be the contents of the first line (title))
    var firstParagraph = context.document.body.paragraphs.getFirst();
    firstParagraph.load("text");

    // get the OOXML representation of the first paragraph
    var ooXML = firstParagraph.getOoxml();

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            // replace the text of the first paragraph with a new text string
            firstParagraph.insertOoxml(ooXML.value.replace(firstParagraph.text, "NEW TITLE"), "Replace");

            return context.sync();
        });

}).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
```

***Note***: If you cannot assume that the first *paragraph* of the document will always be the document title (i.e., if sometimes the document may not have a title, or if sometimes the title may be preceded by one or more blank lines, for example), you'll need to add additional logic to the snippet above to determine whether or not the first *paragraph* of the document is indeed a title, before proceeding with the logic that replaces the contents of the first paragraph.